Are his commands burdensome?
John says Jesus’s commands are not burdensome.


“For this is the love of God, that we keep his commandments. And his commandments are not burdensome.”
‭‭1 John‬ ‭5‬:‭3‬ ‭ESV‬‬


But in Revelation Christ says that the command to not Listen to the teaching is a burden


“But to the rest of you in Thyatira, who do not hold this teaching, who have not learned what some call the deep things of Satan, to you I say, I do not lay on you any other burden.”
‭‭Revelation‬ ‭2‬:‭24‬ ‭ESV‬



I think you may have taken Revelation 2:24 out of context. Verse 25 makes it clear that those Christians who have not followed the false prophetess (verse 20) were under no burden other than "to hold onto what you have until I come."

1 John 5:3 has the Greek word 'barus', meaning 'weighty, heavy'. In the K.J.V. those commands are rendered as not being grievous.
Revelation 2:24 the Greek word is 'baros', meaning 'weight'. In the K.J.V. it is rendered as 'none other burden'.
The sense of weight and heaviness is conveyed, as opposed to a light weight. So, in 1st John 5 God's commands do not bring grief, due to any heaviness. And in Revelation 2 the obedient Christians are assured Christ will not add any more to them. They presently have a burden that they are carrying faithfully.
Noting what Jesus says about the others in the Thyatira congregation, who had acted to cast off the non-burdensome command they are expected to bear, is revealing. This demonstrates what happens when professed Christians do find Christ's commands burdensome.
Clearly, some who had done good works of service, and who had faith, then thought it better to have a Jezebel-type woman acting as a prophetess in their midst, rather than keep the command about preventing such activity. This woman then went on to seduce some in the congregation to commit fornication and idolatry. They therefore exchanged the burden of the Lord (regarding congregational matters) for a burden that turned out to lead to 'great tribulation, except they repent of their deeds.' (Rev. 2:19-22)
But those who remained faithful to the burden of the lord had no such sore afflictions, nor would Christ add any other burden to them. But those who disobeyed had the sore burden of 'great tribulation', and this woman's 'children' being killed.
Those who carried out the Lord's commands were spared such grievous burdens brought on by disobedience.

It could also be worthwhile bringing in the observation "My burden is light" (Matthew ch11 v30), to make the point that being a burden and being burdensome are not the same thing. So the contradiction discovered in the question is slightly artificial.

This could actually stand as an answer I think.

@StephenDisraeli Excellent point. Worthy of another answer, I suggest. A burden does not have to be 'burdensome'.

Whether something is burdensome is relative to the one who bears it. Jesus declared that in Him there is peace, which is true for those who have faith in Him, but not for those without faith.
1 John 5:10 states:

Whoever believes in the Son of God accepts this testimony. Whoever does not believe God has made him out to be a liar, because they have not believed the testimony God has given about his Son. (NIV)

It is noteworthy that it is the Spirit who testifies, and it is the Spirit who relieves the burdens, not we ourselves. 1 John 5:7-8 states:

7 For there are three that testify: 8 the Spirit, the water and the blood; and the three are in agreement. (NIV)

Regarding Revelation 2:24, two statements are noteworthy:

Now I say to the rest of you in Thyatira, to you who do not hold to her teaching and have not learned Satan’s so-called deep secrets, ‘I will not impose any other burden on you, (NIV)

The statement "Satan's so-called deep secrets" refers to the delusions Satan uses to draw people to him. The faithful believers in Thyatira already faced burdens from within the Church, but the Lord promised not to impose any additional burdens ("other burden") to them. This means the Lord will have the Spirit with them to intervene against Satan's seduction and peer pressure, ensuring their faith remains unchallenged.

(Why are people taking a single verse from Revelation and expounding on what they think it means with respect to John's comment about God's commandments?)
It has nothing to do with "burdensome" commandments.
This is one of seven messages to seven churches.
In each, Christ points out what is right or wrong with the church and tells them what he expects them to do in order to correct their situation.
(E.g. in 2:16 he tells the Church at Pergamum: "Repent; or else I will come unto thee quickly".)
Just read what Christ's message to Thyatira actually says in context:
Revelation 2:20,24–26 (KJV):

Notwithstanding I have a few things against thee, because thou sufferest that woman Jezebel, which calleth herself a prophetess, to teach and to seduce my servants to commit fornication, and to eat things sacrificed unto idols.
…
But unto you I say, and unto the rest in Thyatira, as many as have not this doctrine, and which have not known the depths of Satan, as they speak; I will put upon you none other burden.
But that which ye have already hold fast till I come.
And he that overcometh, and keepeth my works unto the end, to him will I give power over the nations:

Revelation 2:20,24–26 (NLT):

“But I have this complaint against you. You are permitting that woman — that Jezebel who calls herself a prophet — to lead my servants astray. She teaches them to commit sexual sin and to eat food offered to idols.
…
“But I also have a message for the rest of you in Thyatira who have not followed this false teaching (‘deeper truths,’ as they call them—depths of Satan, actually). I will ask nothing more of you
except that you hold tightly to what you have until I come.
To all who are victorious, who obey me to the very end, To them I will give authority over all the nations.

A false prophetess has infiltrated the Church in Thyatira and is teaching false doctrine, encouraging the members to sin.
Jesus is speaking to those members that have not accepted her false teaching.
He is not blaming them for this, or asking them to make major changes to their organization as he did with some of the other Churches; he is simply telling them to reject her message and to hold on to the original teachings.
The "other burden" refers to what he is specifically telling each of the Churches to do, not to God's commandments.
It has nothing to do with "his commandments are not burdensome".
